# SymfonyInsight: Critical issue The dependencies of your project could not be installed

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

Since a while, we are facing the following critical issue with SymfonyInsight:

*SymfonyInsight was not able to install your Composer dependencies. If you need to customize files or run commands to make it work, you can edit your SymfonyInsight project configuration to override the default "pre_composer_script" and/or "post_composer_script" settings.*

```
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Nothing to install, update or remove
Package doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package doctrine/reflection is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use roave/better-reflection instead.
Package sensio/distribution-bundle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package sensiolabs/security-checker is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use https://github.com/fabpot/local-php-security-checker instead.
Package zendframework/zend-code is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-code instead.
Package zendframework/zend-eventmanager is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-eventmanager instead.
Package sensio/generator-bundle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/maker-bundle instead.
Generating optimized autoload files
Class Spipu\Html2Pdf\Tests\Parsing\BackgroundErrorTest located in ./vendor/spipu/html2pdf/src/Tests/Image/BackgroundErrorTest.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Spipu\Html2Pdf\Tests\Parsing\BackgroundOkTest located in ./vendor/spipu/html2pdf/src/Tests/Image/BackgroundOkTest.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Spipu\Html2Pdf\Tests\Parsing\SrcErrorTest located in ./vendor/spipu/html2pdf/src/Tests/Image/SrcErrorTest.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Spipu\Html2Pdf\Tests\Parsing\SrcOkTest located in ./vendor/spipu/html2pdf/src/Tests/Image/SrcOkTest.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Spipu\Html2Pdf\Tests\Output\FileNameOkTest located in ./vendor/spipu/html2pdf/src/Tests/Output/FileNameTest.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Tests\DependencyInjection\AddExpressionLanguageProvidersPassTest located in ./vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/Tests/DependencyInjection/Compiler/AddExpressionLanguageProvidersPassTest.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Tests\DependencyInjection\AddParamConverterPassTest located in ./vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/Tests/DependencyInjection/Compiler/AddParamConverterPassTest.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Tests\Request\ParamConverter\ArgumentNameConverterTest located in ./vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/Tests/Request/ArgumentNameConverterTest.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
composer/package-versions-deprecated: Generating version class...
composer/package-versions-deprecated: ...done generating version class
composer/package-versions-deprecated: You should rely on the Composer\InstalledVersions class instead of this package as you are using Composer 2. You can require composer-runtime-api:^2 to ensure it is present.
39 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
> Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters
Creating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache

Fatal error: Declaration of Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface::get($id, $invalidBehavior = self::EXCEPTION_ON_INVALID_REFERENCE) must be compatible with Psr\Container\ContainerInterface::get(string $id) in /home/foobar/code/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerInterface.php on line 25

In ContainerInterface.php line 25:
                                                                               
  Compile Error: Declaration of Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Contain  
  erInterface::get($id, $invalidBehavior = self::EXCEPTION_ON_INVALID_REFEREN  
  CE) must be compatible with Psr\Container\ContainerInterface::get(string $i  
  d)                                                                           
                                                                               

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the symfony-scripts event terminated with an exception

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  Fatal error: Declaration of Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface::get($id, $invalidBehavior = self::EXCEPTION_ON_INVALID_REFERENCE) must be compatible with Psr\Container\ContainerInterface::get(string $id) in /home/foobar/code/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerInterface.php on line 25  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  In ContainerInterface.php line 25:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    Compile Error: Declaration of Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Contain                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    erInterface::get($id, $invalidBehavior = self::EXCEPTION_ON_INVALID_REFEREN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    CE) must be compatible with Psr\Container\ContainerInterface::get(string $i                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    d)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-suggest] [--no-dev] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-install] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Any clue of what's the dependency that created this issue ?

Comment: looks like u switched from composer 1 to composer 2 :/ easy solution probably using composer 1, what php version are u using? looks like php <= 7.2 did u try with newer? the error is probably about typehinting introduced in later versions

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? The error message provides some hints, so why not resolve them?

Comment: Hi John, as defined in Symfony project configuation file, we tried to use php 7.2 and php 7.4, and composer versions 1 and 2. Still facing the same issue